# How to place beads evenly over another mesh?

Tags: modifiers

I made a skirt and want to place beads over it. I need them to fill all surface of the skirt evenly, with the same distance between each bead, repeating the form of a skirt, if it makes sense. Is there any way to do it automatically? Thank you!

[image]

[image: topology]

Comment: Did you deform the skirt  yourself, from a flat starting mesh? Can you show us the topology? Following a regular topology might be the easiest route.. another consideration.. if you have a regular UV map, might it be acceptable to create the illusion of beads in a shader, rather than geometry?

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank your for your reply. I added an image of topology. The skirt was made in Marvelous Designer and remeshed in Blender afterwards. As for the beads, I'd rather add them as a geometry (if I'll understand how) :)

Comment: Thanks. Is that black dot the size of a bead?

Comment: Yes, it's the size of a bead

Comment: If it was OK with you, you could  share the skirt, or a bit of it,  on https://blend-exchange.com, so folks can check out their methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the skirt topology, you could use *Instancing*, first activate the Object > Instancing > Faces option of the skirt:

[image]

Put the bead object at the same location as the skirt, parent it to the skirt, it will be instanced all over the skirt:

[image]

Result:

[image]

You could also bake the normals in order to fake the 3D relief.

Comment: Thank you so much!